# Proving $\langle v_1,\dots ,v_n\rangle_K = \langle w_1,\dots ,w_n\rangle_K$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $K$ be a field, $ V$ a $K$ vector space and $v_1,...,v_n \in V$. We define $w_i:=\sum_{j=1}^{i}{v_j}$.

I have to show that $\langle v_1,\dots ,v_n\rangle_K = \langle w_1,\dots ,w_n\rangle_K$.

**My idea:**

"$\subseteq$"
$$\langle v_1,\dots ,v_n\rangle_K \subseteq \langle w_1,...,w_n \rangle _K  
\iff \{\lambda _1 v_1+\cdots + \lambda _n v_n : \lambda_1,...,\lambda_n \in K \} \subseteq \{r_1w_1+\cdots r_nw_n : r_1,...,r_n\in K \} \\
\iff \{\lambda _1 v_1+\cdots + \lambda _n v_n : \lambda_1,...,\lambda_n \in K \} \subseteq \{v_1(r_1+\cdots + r_n)+\cdots +r_nv_n : r_1, ...r_n\in K \}$$
This is true, setting $\lambda_i=r_i+\cdots + r_n$ ($i=1,...,n-1$).

I would use an analogous argument for the other side. Is that correct?

Comment: No, for the inclusion that you have tackled, you have to show that you can find the $r_i$, given the $\lambda_i$. That means you have to express each $r_i$ in terms of the $\lambda_i$, whereas what you've done is the other way around. Indeed, what you have written is a proof of the other inclusion.

Comment: Okay, you're right - but how can I express $r_i$ in terms of $\lambda _i$?

Comment: $r_1$ is easy. Once you've got $r_1$, $r_2$ is easy. Once you've got $r_1$ and $r_2$, $r_3$ is easy. And so on.

Comment: Could you elaborate??

Comment: Sorry, probably better to start at the other end. It's easy to express $r_n$ in terms of the $\lambda_i$. Once you've done that, it's easy to express $r_{n-1}$ in terms of the $\lambda_i$. And then continue working your way toward expressing $r_1$ in terms of the $\lambda_i$.

Comment: $r_n=\lambda_n$, $r_{n-1}=\lambda_{n-1}-\lambda_n$, $r_{n-2}=\lambda_{n-2}+\lambda_{n-1}+\lambda_n$, right?

Comment: $r_{n-2}=\lambda_{n-2}-r_{n-1}-r_n=\lambda_{n-2}-(\lambda_{n-1}-\lambda_n)-\lambda_n=\lambda_{n-2}-\lambda_{n-1}$.

Comment: Thanks, I get it know. But how can I notate that recursion economically?

Comment: Don't you see a pattern? If not, do a few more, until you see.

Comment: I'd say $r_{n-i}=\lambda_{n-i}+\lambda_{n-i+1}$

Comment: Does that match up with the formulas for $r_{n-1}$ and $r_{n-2}$?

Comment: Yes, $i=1$, then $r_{n-1}=\lambda_{n-1}+\lambda_{n}$, and $i=2$ aswell.

Comment: But the formula you got a few comments up was $r_{n-1}=\lambda_{n-1}-\lambda_n$, and the formula I gave was $r_{n-2}=\lambda_{n-2}-\lambda_{n-1}$, which is not what you are writing now.

Answer (score 1):

An approach using linear transformations:

Note that $\langle v_1,\dots,v_n \rangle$ is the image of the linear transformation $f: K^n \to V$ defined by
$$
f(a_1,\dots,a_n) = a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_n v_n.
$$
Let $g:K^n \to K^n$ denote the map $g(x) = Mx$ where 
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&1&\cdots&1\\
0&1&\cdots & 1\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1}.
$$
Because $g$ is invertible, $f \circ g$ has the same image as $f$. However, the image of $f \circ g$ is $\langle w_1,\dots,w_n \rangle$.